# How Can I Make My Sidebar Like This Website's?

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning how to code html and css and I am not trying to copy them I just want to learn how to do it like that. Yes it's a CS:GO gambling site I know. I want to learn how to add the font awesome icon and make it clickable and also how to add a padding around only that icon. The website: skinup.gg

My Test Website: https://jsfiddle.net/a2yweme3/

HTML:

```
        <!--Default Stuff-->
    <title>CS:GOAbyss</title>

    <!--Script Links-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    <!--Website Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">TEST LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST LINK</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* Default Stuff */
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Website Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
width:180px;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}

ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul li {
list-style:none;
padding:10px;
border-bottom:2px solid #111;
display: block;
}

ul li a {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
color:#ccc;
text-decoration:none;
margin:10px;
}

ul li:before {
content:'\f1ce';
font-family:'FontAwesome';
padding:10px;
background:rgb(125,125,125);
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple with font-awesome icons, but you can make custom icons by creating pictures and adding :hover to create a hover effect on the pics (it's how that skin site is doing it).

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naucodt4/)

Updated: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fft53zq9/)

Add icons like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="#" class="navbarLinks">
      <div class="icons">
         <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="textInfo">TEST LINK
      </div>
   </a>
</li>
```

And create a hover effect on the fontawesome icon by doing this:

```
.fa-money:hover{
   color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I want it to stay the same as it looks now. How can I not change the look at all but just change how the icons works and also how can i make it so the whole box is a link?

Comment: You should try and learn yourself imo. Anyhow, I've made the changes in the updated fiddle.